# UTF8 output instead of ISO-8859-1 java Linux

Tags: java, linux, encoding

Application (Java 1.6) runs on Linux platform and i create a file with ISO-8859-1 encoding
like this

```
 File localTempDir = new File(tempDir);
 String encoding = TextUtils.ISO_8859_1;

    try {
        String fileName = String.format(fileNameFormat, sdf.format(new Date()));
        tmpFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "", localTempDir);
        log.info("Created file " + tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;

        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(encoding)){
            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpFile), Charset.forName(encoding));
        }else{
            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpFile));
        }

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        out.write(content);

        log.debug("With content " + content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to create file", e);
    }
    return tmpFile;
}`
```

But still get a file with UTF8 encoding. Any Ideas why?

Comment: How do you determine that output encoding is UTF-8? Also, are you sure that `TextUtils.ISO_8859_1` is not blank?

Comment: TextUtils.ISO_8859_1 is a constant defined in another class.
To determine file encoding i run command file -bi <filename>.

Comment: One problem with text constants in other classes: if the constant is changed, the compiled using class might have the OLD value due to optimizing. Do a clean build then.

Comment: Try to initialize `content` with characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 (i.e. `content = "\u0420"`), and look at the output file in text editor. If these characters are replaced with `?`, output encoding is actually ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify first. Try this:

```
File localTempDir = new File(tempDir);
String encoding = "ISO-8859-1"; // "Cp1252" = Windows Latin 1

try {
    String fileName = String.format(fileNameFormat, sdf.format(new Date()));
    tmpFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "", localTempDir);
    log.info("Created file " + tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());

    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;

    if (!encoding.isEmpty()) {
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpFile), encoding);
    } else {
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpFile));
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter));
    try {
        out.print(content);

        log.debug("With content " + content);
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Failed to create file", e);
}
return tmpFile;
```

}

Comment: The problem is that i have a jvm parameter on my tomcat 6 -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 and if i remove it i get correct encoding. Any ideas why?

Comment: That is the System property for the default encoding. Also both source codes above use ISO-8859-1. So the file should be generated as ISO-8859-1. If that is seen as "wrong" maybe on the reading side there is a problem. A hex editor should help there.